# Detect IE in PHP then open webpage

Tags: php, internet-explorer

How can i detect any-IE in php , if any-ie then continue open page,

else non-ie this page can't open page then show error?

I'm using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to detect user's browser..

thx u lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if($browser['browser'] != 'Internet Explorer') {
  die('Only IE');
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: requires browsercap.ini, huge file, probably not worth it for this particular scenario. not saying it's not a viable solution

Comment: If someone force users to use particular browser I think that he need one functionality that only this browser (at the moment) has. One can use `get_browser` to verify handling of this functionality in given browser. Of course there are simpler and faster ways to do that, for instance plain regexp but this should resolve all the problems. Anyway, thanks for pointing out requirements that I've forgotten.

Comment: yes, i can't use it, mush include browscap.ini ...-_-.